# Omniture SiteCatalyst WATS addon

Tags: firefox-addon, adobe-analytics

I have a Flex Application, and I need to track site catalyst data with Omniture site-catalyst.
For testing the data, I am using WATS addon on ForeFox. All is going very fine, except to get site data in Report Suite History Panel of WATS addon, which available on bottom of this addon. Because I am not getting any data in Report Suite History Panel of WATS addon.
However with some suggestions, I tried different versions of Firefox, but all is in vain till now.

Thanks.
Himanshu Pareek

Comment: Oh, I got it. 
I added WATS version 0.3 and its working also for Report Suite Data Track. But be sure you have a firefox version below FF4.0, otherwise you won't be able to add WATS version 0.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the WATS addon you could also modify the firefox configuration by entering "about:config" into the address bar.

Next you add the following entry ("extensions.checkCompatibility.4.0" (without quotes)) by right-clicking the browser -> new -> boolean. Set the boolean to false.

The "extensions.checkCompatibility.version" item will change the behavior of extensions checking the Firefox version. When, for example, you're working with Firefox 9 and want to use the WATS extension. You can add the compatibility setting: "extensions.checkCompatibility.version.9.0" (without quotes).

If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I got it. I was facing this problem with the latest version of WATS addon as 0.31, but when I  added WATS version 0.30 its working for Report Suite Data Track. But be sure you have a firefox version below FF4.0, otherwise you won't be able to add WATS version 0.30 Thanks.